# How to use POST data using navigate in VBS

Tags: vba, post, vbscript, web-scraping

Currently I'm trying to write a function to post data to an IE window in VBS. I'm trying to modify a function I wrote in VBA which works well:

```
Sub IEPostStringRequest(URL As String, FormData As String, WebBrowser As InternetExplorer, TargetName As String)
  'Send the form data To URL As POST request
  Dim bFormData() As Byte
  ReDim bFormData(Len(FormData) - 1)

  bFormData = StrConv(FormData, vbFromUnicode)

  WebBrowser.Navigate URL, 2 + 4 + 8, TargetName, bFormData, _
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + Chr(10) + Chr(13)
  WebBrowser.Navigate
End Sub
```

You send it a URL, query string as FormData, an InternetExplorer object which already exists, and a target frame and it sends the post request to that frame. However, StrConv doesn't work in VBS and I haven't found a suitable replacement for it. It also seems like there must be a better way, because sending a post request is fairly simple. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8531&lngWId=4

Answer (score 0):

Try `ADODB.Stream` ActiveX to convert string to binary array of bytes:

```
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Open
    .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
    .Charset = "us-ascii"
    .WriteText FormData
    .Position = 0
    .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
    bFormData = .Read
    .Close
End With
```